# Is there any way to find unique count of values in a column in mysql from stat like table_rows in information_schema.tables?

Tags: mysql

I want to find the approximate unique count of values in a column of table in mysql.

```
select count( Distinct col1) from table1;
```

Need replacement of above query with approximate value. 
count(Distinct Col1) takes too much time and i just want the approx value like table_rows in information_schema.tables

Comment: MySQL 8.0 has histograms "Value 4: The number of distinct values in the range from the bucket lower value to its upper value. " https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/optimizer-statistics.html which can be accesed within the INFORMATION_SCHEMA database.. But is **not approximated** because histograms is using by MySQL 8.0 to optimize query plans.. But i think this only comes close what you want.

Comment: Besides `select count( Distinct col1) from table1;` can be optimized with a index on `col1` to make it execute faster.  see demo https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/gY3Zh2ZsQ2buARof7QnuRQ/0 .. You can see it can use a index

Comment: we have only select rights we are not allowed to create indexes.

Comment: "we have only select rights we are not allowed to create indexes" Ask somebody to make one that does has right to create a index.

Comment: Is there any replacement of  APPROX_COUNT_DISTINCT(used in oracle) in my sql? We have only select rights we can't create any histogram or index.

Comment: Thanks for your help.I will discuss with my seniors.

Answer (score -1):

You can use 'approximate' as below
`select approximate count(distinct col1) from table`

Comment: No you can't `approximate` is not valid MySQL syntax.